# Can I use C++ char array without setting the size?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a C++ char array `char itemNo[10];`

Is there an any way to create it without fixing the size. Because later if I want to add more length, this matters.

Comment: When you say "C++ string", most people think of the `std::string` class.  Which can indeed grow and shrink at need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is not a C++ string. It is a C string and, no, you may not use it without pre-setting the size.

A C++ string is `std::string itemNo` and, yes, you may use it without pre-setting the size.